# My oil light says oil is at 4% can I add a quart of oil to take my percentage up

Tags: oil-change

My oil is down to 4% can I add oil until my oil change

Comment: Please clarify, is your oil _level_ down to 4% or your oil _life_ down to 4%? If it is indeed 'oil level', then you need to stop driving Immediately (if not sooner) and have the oil replenished. Also note however that I know of no car that reports oil level like this, so it is more plausible that it is 'oil life' that is at 4%, in which case you should have your oil and filter changed soon.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Anyway, always check the dipstick (twice: wipe and dip it again) before adding oil, and make a judgement from the present level. Never just tip oil in unless the oil sump is known to be empty (because you drained it).

Answer (score 3):

First, no, adding a quart of oil will just give you an over-full crankcase. What you are seeing is an ***oil life meter***, not an oil level meter. The oil level is completely separate and will pop a separate light on your dash. Considering this ... your oil isn't going to magically disappear or become unusable when your oil life meter gets to zero. The oil will still work, it just won't be optimal. Obviously you should try to get the oil changed as soon as possible (as @GlenYates stated in the comments).